# Rails Nesteds Forms with dynamic fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Assuming I have a recipe table that has a field for name. The form would look something like this:

```
<%= form_with(model: recipe, local: true) do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :name %>
  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

but if recipe is related to  ingredients (which contains a name fields) through an intermediate table with the amount of the ingredient.
how should i do the form to create a recipe, choose the ingredient and enter the amount of the ingredient. And also have the option to generate more fields if the recipe has more than one ingredient. All that in one form.
Something like that:

```
<%= form_with(model: recipe, local: true) do |form| %>

  <%= form.text_field :name %>

  (select field to choose an ingredient)

  (field for recipe_ingredient to ingress the amount of the ingredient)

  (button to generate more fields for other ingredients)

  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

rails version: 5.2.2

Comment: Take a look at the `cocoon` gem. I believe this does exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. For the moment i was trying to do it without use gems. Maybe in the future ill give it a look.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is one of the harder things to do in rails because it requires building the form on the server and then editing the form on the browser with js when the user adds or removes fields. I'll try to show the bare minimum working example.

Lets first build the form on the server with [fields_for](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for) which lets you add nested fields for a model that `accepts_nested_fields_for` one of its relationships. In your case you will need to nest your form twice (first for the `Recipe`'s `Dose`s and second for each `Dose`'s `Ingredient`). Users won't realy see the `Dose` model as it is only there as an intermediate table.

Let's say you've set up your app like this:

```
rails g scaffold Ingredient name:string

rails g scaffold Recipe name:string

rails g scaffold Dose ingredient:references recipe:references amount:decimal
```

Then add this to the `Recipe` model:

```
has_many :doses
has_many :ingredients, through: :doses

accepts_nested_attributes_for :doses, allow_destroy: true
```

And this to the `Dose` model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredient
```

Now edit the `app/views/recipes/_form.html.erb` file and add the fields for `Dose`

```
<%= form.fields_for :doses do |dose_form| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= dose_form.label :_destroy %>
    <%= dose_form.check_box :_destroy %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= dose_form.label :ingredient_id %>
    <%= dose_form.select :ingredient_id, @ingredients %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= dose_form.label :amount %>
    <%= dose_form.number_field :amount %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This won't do very much since fields_for will only generate the code inside its block if the relationship is populated. So let's populate the `recipe`'s `doses` relationship in the `new` and `edit` actions of the `app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb` file. While we're there let's add all the ingredients to our `@ingredients` variable, and permit our nested attributes to the [strong_parameters](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) `permitted` hash.

```
def new
  @recipe = Recipe.new
  @ingredients = Ingredient.all.pluck(:name, :id)
  1.times{ @recipe.doses.build } 
end

def edit
  @ingredients = Ingredient.all.pluck(:name, :id)
end
...

def recipe_params
  params.require(:recipe).permit(:name, doses_attributes: [:id, :ingredient_id, :amount, :_destroy])
end
```

You can build as many doses as you want, and once we setup the js part we can 'build' them on the front end. 1 is fine for now, just to show our dose fields.

Run the migrations and start the server and create a few [ingredients](http://localhost:3000/ingredients) then you will see them in the drop downs when creating a new [recipe](http://localhost:3000/recipes/new)

Now you have a working nested field solution, but we have to build the doses in the backend and send the rendered form to the browser with a set number of built doses. Let's add some js to allow users to create and destroy nested fields on the fly.

Destroying fields is easy, since we have it all setup already. We just need to hide the field if the `_destroy` checkbox is on. To do that let's install Stimulus

```
bundle exec rails webpacker:install:stimulus
```

And let's create a new stimulus controller in `app/javascript/controllers/fields_for_controller.js`

```
import {Controller} from "stimulus"
export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ["fields"]

  hide(e){
    e.target.closest("[data-target='fields-for.fields']").style = "display: none;"
  }
}
```

And update our `app/views/recipes/_form.html.erb` to use the controller:

```
<div data-controller="fields-for">
  <%= form.fields_for :doses do |dose_form| %>
    <div data-target="fields-for.fields">
      <div class="field">
        <%= dose_form.label :_destroy %>
        <%= dose_form.check_box :_destroy, {data: {action: "fields-for#hide"}} %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= dose_form.label :ingredient_id %>
        <%= dose_form.select :ingredient_id, @ingredients %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= dose_form.label :amount %>
        <%= dose_form.number_field :amount %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Great, now we hide the field when the user clicks the checkbox, and the backend will destroy the dose because the checkbox is checked.

Now let's look at the html `nested_fields` generates to get some ideas of how we might let users add and remove them:

```
<div data-target="fields-for.fields">
      <div>
        <label for="recipe_doses_attributes_0__destroy">Destroy</label>
        <input name="recipe[doses_attributes][0][_destroy]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input data-action="fields-for#hide" type="checkbox" value="1" name="recipe[doses_attributes][0][_destroy]" id="recipe_doses_attributes_0__destroy" />
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <label for="recipe_doses_attributes_0_ingredient_id">Ingredient</label>
        <select name="recipe[doses_attributes][0][ingredient_id]" id="recipe_doses_attributes_0_ingredient_id"><option value="1">first ingredient</option>
<option selected="selected" value="2">second ingredient</option>
<option value="3">second ingredient</option></select>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <label for="recipe_doses_attributes_0_amount">Amount</label>
        <input type="number" value="2.0" name="recipe[doses_attributes][0][amount]" id="recipe_doses_attributes_0_amount" />
      </div>
    </div>
<input type="hidden" value="3" name="recipe[doses_attributes][0][id]" id="recipe_doses_attributes_0_id" />
```

The interesting bit is `recipe[doses_attributes][0][ingredient_id]` specifically the `[0]` it turns out `fields_for` assigns an incremental `child_index` to each of the built `doses`. The backend uses that `child_index` to know which children to delete or which attributes to update on which child.

So now the answer is clear, we just need to insert the same `<div>` `fields_for` created and set the `child_index` of this new inserted `<div>` to a higher value than the highest value previously in the form. Remember this is only an `index`, not an `id`, which means we can set it to a very big number since Rails will only use it to keep the nested fields attributes in the same group and actually assign `id`s when saving the records.

So now we have to make two choices:

1. Where to get the incremental index from
2. Where to get the `fields_for` `<div>` from

For the first choice the usual answer is to just get the current time and use that as `child_index`

For the second one the usual way is to move the html block into its own partial in `app/views/doses/_fields.html.erb` then render that block twice inside the form in `app/bies/recipes/_form.htm.erb`. Once inside the `form.fields_for` loop. And a second time inside the data attribute of a `button` where we create a new form just to generate one `field_for`:

```
<div data-controller="fields-for">
  <%= form.fields_for :doses do |dose_form| %>
    <%= render "doses/fields", dose_form: dose_form %>
  <% end %>
  <%= button_tag("Add Dose", {data: { action: "fields-for#add", fields: form.fields_for(:doses, Dose.new, child_index:"new_field"){|dose_form| render("doses/fields", dose_form: dose_form)}}}) %>
</div>
```

Then use js to get the partial from the button's data tag update the `child_index` and insert the updated html into the form. Since the button already has `data-action='fields-for#add'` we just need to add the add action to our `app/javascript/controllers/fields_for_controller.js`

```
add(e){
  e.preventDefault()
  e.target.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', e.target.dataset.fields.replace(/new_field/g, new Date().getTime()))
}
```

Now we don't need to build the `doses` beforehand. Using a gem for this is a lot simpler, but the advantage of this is you can set it up exactly as you need and it doesn't add any code to your app that isn't needed.

Also it just occurred to me that `Portion` would have been a better name for `Dose`

Comment: Thanks. It helped me with the nested forms. When I manage to add some fields dynamically, I'll be back to comment again how I did it in case its useful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative option would be to use a gem like https://github.com/schneems/wicked

This way you can build a multi-step form and have data in the form based on 'the previous step'.

Also a great gem for doing anything nested - https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

Comment: Thanks. For the moment i was trying to do it without use gems. Maybe in the future ill give a look to those gems..