# When trying to dynamically render new forms, the entire page is reloaded

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I am working on this ruby on rails project in which users can add ingredients to recipes. Right now on the new recipe page, a user can only add 1 ingredient, I would like them to be able to add many ingredients when creating or editing a recipe. I tried to this, and as far as I can tell everything seems to be in order, but the 'add ingredient' link simply reloads the entire page.

_form.html.erb

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app/assets/stylesheets/form.css">
<div id = "form">
  <%= form_for(@recipe) do |form| %>
    <% if @recipe.errors.any? %>
      <div id = "error_explanation">
        <h2>
          <%= pluralize(@recipe.errors.count, "error") %>
          prohibited this recipe from being saved:
        </h2>
        <ul>
          <%@recipe.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <p>
      <%= form.label :title  %><br>
      <%= form.text_field :title %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <%= form.label :author  %><br>
      <%= form.text_field :author %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <%= form.label :note %><br>
      <%= form.text_area :note %>
    </p>
    <h2 id = "add">Add an Ingredient: </h2>
    <%= form.fields_for :ingredients do |builder| %>
      <%= render 'ingredient_fields', form: builder %>
    <% end %>

    <%= link_to_add_fields "Add Ingredient", form, :ingredients %>
    <p>
      <%= form.submit %>
    </p>

  <% end %>
</div>
```

_ingredient_field.html.erb

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app/assets/stylesheets/ingredient_form.css">

<p class = "input_field">
  <%= form.label :name, "name" %><br>
  <%= form.text_field :name %>
</p>
<p class = "input_field">
  <%= form.label :amount, "amount" %><br>
  <%= form.number_field :amount %>
</p>
<p class = "input_field">
  <%= form.label :uom, "UOM" %><br>
  <%= form.text_field :uom %>
</p>
</br>
```

recipe.rb

```
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :name, :ingredients_attributes
  has_many :ingredients, :dependent => :delete_all
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients, reject_if: :all_blank
  validates :title, presence: true, length: {minimum: 4}
  validates :author, presence: true
end
```

application_helper.erb

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def link_to_add_fields(name, form, association)
    new_object = form.object.send(association).klass.new
    id = new_object.object_id
    fields = form.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
      render(association.to_s.singularize + '_fields', form: builder)
    end
    link_to(name, '#', class: 'add_fields', data:
        { id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", '') })
  end
end
```

recipe.js.coffee - this is what I am most suspicious of. I don't really understand jQuery and coffeescript. I have this file inside javascript/packs and am using require("packs/recipes") in application.html.erb.

```
jQuery ->
  $('form').on 'click', '.add_fields', (event) ->
  time = new Date().getTime()
  regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
  $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
  event.preventDefault()
```

thank you

Comment: You may want to look into this gem: https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it simple, you need to use [Rails nested forms](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms). But the thing is, you also need what Rails Guides called ["Adding Fields on the Fly"](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#adding-fields-on-the-fly). As you can see, Rails don't support this need directly. But it can be achieved very easily with javascript. I don't want to explain all the processes here because there is a great answer about that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58206985/10939108. Also, you can use [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) gem to achieve this functionality too.